# What exactly is a git local repository?

Tags: git, directory, repository

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to conceptualize the idea of a "local repository" better in my head. Can someone help clarify what is a local repository?

Here's my understanding so far. Inside an existing working directory I can initialize a git local repository, which will create the .git file. This acts as a file that will track the history of my directory for the future (commits, etc.) This "local repository" keeps track of the files in the working directory, the staging area/index where files get added, and the HEAD where it points to the most recent commit. How can I formalize the definition of a local repository?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this answer in another question can help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31981095/2854555

Basically a *repository* is a place functioning you said, **stored** as a directory (`.git`). But the procedure it "keeps track of the files" is not entirely automatic -- you should tell it what to keep track of and do your commit (and so on).

In git, the different between *local* and *remote* is quite small, because git is *distributed*. You can consider *remote* as a copy of *local*, so don't worry about *local* or *remote* that much.

Answer (score 0):

Git has two repository types: local and remote.  The local repo is on your computer for only your direct use.  The remote repo is typically elsewhere and for your indirect use.  Git supports multiple remote repositories.

**Remote Repo:**

Typically, we work in teams and need to work on a codebase together.  The codebase is on a “central” server and people retrieve files from it and commit to it.

Git refers to the centralized server as a “remote repository”.  The remote repo is usually not on your machine and is the one shared by the team. The team “pushes” commits to it when ready to share with the team. While one of your remote repos could be another team member’s local repo, in a corporate environment at least one (or the only!) is typically a Git repo on a server anointed as the central/official repo.

Note that a remote repo is optional.  When not sharing code with others, there is technically no need for a remote repo (you may want one for backup or CI).  There is also no need for a remote repo if your local repo is considered the central one by all team members (which means your local repo is their remote repo).

**Local Repo:**

The local repo is on your computer and has all the files and their commit history, enabling full diffs, history review, and committing when offline.  This is one of the key features of a “distributed” version control system (DVCS), locally having the full repository history.

Check out the image on the link: 
[**Concept of Git Repository**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi1RY.png)